# Configuring Kaltura module in drupal 7

Tags: installation

I am trying to configure the [Kaltura](https://www.drupal.org/project/kaltura) module in Drupal 7. If I try adding the partner ID, email ID, and password (which I have received from [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/)'s website), it gives me the following error:

> Class 'KalturaUser' not found

I also added the library but it's not working. Could anyone tell me how to configure the Kaltura module?

Comment: The `KalturaUser` class is defined in KalturaTypes.php; if you added the library, you should not get any error. Probably the error is caused by not saving the library in the right directory. From the make file used from the module, I would assume KalturaTypes.php should be located in libraries/KalturaClient/KalturaTypes.php.

Comment: I have placed KalturaTypes.php in KalturaClient folder but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to Kaltura module documentation here http://cgit.drupalcode.org/kaltura/plain/README.txt?h=7.x-3.2

You should download the php version of API from here   (http://cdnbakmi.kaltura.com/content/clientlibs/php5_16-12-2014.tar.gz) and place it under DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/all/libraries/KalturaClient directory.

Note: The directory name is case-sensitive.

Alternatively you can use drush for this.Here is a command for drush.

```
    Drush kaltura-client-install
```